# Material UI+ React - How to link a component to perform navigation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-dom

I'm using the Drawer Component in MUI v.5 to create a responsive navigation bar. However, I don't know how to link and perform another page after clicking on them (for example after clicking on the "About" button on the navbar, it will be directed to about.js.)
I would really appreciate your help!

I created a DrawerComp.js for responsive navbar

```js
//DrawerComp.js
        import React, { useState} from 'react'
        import {Drawer, IconButton, List, ListItemButton, ListItemIcon, ListItemText} from '@mui/material';
        import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
    
        const PAGES = ["About", "Socials"]
        const DrawerComp =()=>{
    
            const [openDrawer, setOpenDrawer]=useState(false);
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Drawer PaperProps={{sx:{ width:240}}} open={openDrawer} onClose={()=>setOpenDrawer(false)}>
                    <List>
                        {
                            PAGES.map((page,index)=>(
                                <ListItemButton onClick={()=> setOpenDrawer(false)} key={index}>
                                <ListItemIcon>
                                    <ListItemText>
                                    {page}
                                    </ListItemText>
                                </ListItemIcon>
                            </ListItemButton>
                            ))
                        }
                       
                    </List>
                    </Drawer>
                    <IconButton onClick={()=>setOpenDrawer(!openDrawer)} > <MenuIcon/></IconButton>
                   
                   
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        };
    
        export default DrawerComp;
```

and here is what I have on navbar.js

```js
 //navbar.js
        import { AppBar, Toolbar, IconButton, Typography, Stack, Button,Box, useMediaQuery, useTheme, Tabs, Tab } from "@mui/material"
    
        import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react';
        import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
        import DrawerComp from "./DrawerComp";
    
    
        const PAGES = ["About", "Socials"];
        const Navbar = (props) => {
            const { data: session, status } = useSession();
            const [value, setValue] = useState();
            const theme = useTheme();
            const isMatch = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));
    
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                <AppBar position='static'>
                    <Toolbar>
                        
                        {
                            isMatch ?(
                                <>
                                <DrawerComp sx={{marginLeft: 4}}/>
                                 <Box component="img" sx={{ height: 50, width: 50, mx:"auto"}}  alt='my_img' src='/static/images/my_img.png' />
                                 
                                </>
                            ) : (
                                <>
                               
                            <Tabs  textColor='#000' >
                                {
                                    PAGES.map((page,index) => (
                                        <Tab  key={index} label={page}></Tab>
                                    ))
                                }
                            
                        </Tabs>
    
    
                                </>
                            )
                        }
    
                       
                    </Toolbar>
                    
                </AppBar>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        }
    
        export default Navbar;
```

Comment: I have given an answer based on the info you provided, however adding more info (like adding about.js code) would be better, so I can edit my answer **if needed**

Answer (score 0):

for soft loading, since you are creating an spa application, i suggest using [react-router-dom](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

what you need to do is 2 things:

1. use `useNavigate()` to navigate to other page
2. route the `about` page in your frontend

and on a side note, put everything inside `about.js` inside a component, let's call it `AboutComp`

for step 1 :

in App.js:

```js
import {Router,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import AboutComp from './about.js' // an example import, so do it the way your project is set
import DrawerComp from "./DrawerComp"


function App(){
      return(
         <Router>
          <Route path='about' element = {<AboutComp/>}/>
          <Route path='' element = {<DrawerComp/>}/>
    </Router>
)
}
```

now, for step 2, inside `DrawerComp` file:

```js
 import React, { useState} from 'react'
 import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
        import {Drawer, IconButton, List, ListItemButton, ListItemIcon, ListItemText} from '@mui/material';
        import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
    
        const PAGES = ["About", "Socials"]
        const DrawerComp =()=>{
            const redirect = useNavigate() //this the re-direct api
            const handleRedirect = (e)=>{
                  redirect(e.target.value) //if you go to the jsx part, you can  see that i added a button to `{page}` and added a value to the button to be the page itself
                  
                    
}
    
            const [openDrawer, setOpenDrawer]=useState(false);
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Drawer PaperProps={{sx:{ width:240}}} open={openDrawer} onClose={()=>setOpenDrawer(false)}>
                    <List>
                        {
                            PAGES.map((page,index)=>(
                                <ListItemButton onClick={()=> setOpenDrawer(false)} key={index}>
                                <ListItemIcon>
                                    <ListItemText>
                                    <button value={page} onClick={(e)=>handleRedirect(e)}>{page}</button>
                                    </ListItemText>
                                </ListItemIcon>
                            </ListItemButton>
                            ))
                        }
                       
                    </List>
                    </Drawer>
                    <IconButton onClick={()=>setOpenDrawer(!openDrawer)} > <MenuIcon/></IconButton>
                   
                   
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        };
    
        export default DrawerComp;
```

now ofc, you can style the button to be transparent to the ListItemButton background, or the way it suit you.